# Objective C - The network connection was lost" error while Downloading file using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, uikit, afnetworking

I am using Reachability Code of [Tony Million](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)
and in the unreachable block i am trying to pause the download but each time the internet Disconnects before the download is paused **AFNetworking** returns with failure with error message "The network connection was lost" thus unable to resume the download so what should be Done?

This is what i have done in **Application Delegate**

```
__weak MTCAppDelegate *weakself = self;
Reachability * reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];


reach.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability * reachability)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[AFDROSingleton sharedInstance] resume];
        for (UIView *subview in [weakself.window subviews]) {
            if (subview.tag == 20) {
                [subview removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
    });
};

reach.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability * reachability)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        MTCReachability *reach = [[MTCReachability alloc] initWithFrame:weakself.window.frame];
        [reach setTag:20];
        [weakself.window addSubview:reach];
        [weakself.window bringSubviewToFront:reach];
       [[AFDROSingleton sharedInstance] pause];
    });
};

[reach startNotifier];
```

Comment: so? What is the problem?

Comment: Read the Question Carefully...

Comment: Check out AFDownloadRequestOperation, which builds a lot of support for downloading and resuming files.  You will be able to resume downloads after a network failure using this. https://github.com/steipete/AFDownloadRequestOperation

Comment: Downloads can be resumed only if the server supports Range headers. AFDownloadRequestOperation can't help if your server can't send Range headers.

Comment: What Mugnuth suggested above is most likely will be the case. Does your server supports rangeHeaders?

Comment: The orignal problem is that the server supports range headers and while using the **AFDownloadingRequestOperation** the temporary file for the download is created but that when the reach ability allows notifies the dissconnection the AFNetwork fails with error before the pause is called.

Answer (score 1):

There is reachability code from the Apple sample that has been updated to ARC.

I've put it into the Reachability project in Xcode 4.6.3.  If you are interested I can send your way if you need it.

Comment: yes please send me; my email is quamber@gmail.com . if that works fine i will accept this answer

Comment: Just emailed.  Cheers.  I've been screwing around with it.  Please feel free to change my edits back.  I commented out lines 41+ within applicationDidFinishLaunching in the AppDelegate.

Comment: No Alex i am finalizing my android project so was unable to check the code.will start on this project after that